# Recatjs fecth api unable to get business error

Tags: reactjs

I have written fetch api to call spring boot api.
In network tab 400 bad request and business error message is coming in response.
Can anyone guide me how to retrieve custom error message from response object.

Comment: Check out the network tab and see if you get any error messages. If not, you need to check at the backed or try to check with documentation and see if you are sending right params and body.

Comment: The error message would depend on your API. You'd need to go in and adjust that if you want to send something in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a [minimal reproducible examle](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of things you have tried.

You have to provide the custom error message at the spring controller or create a specific ExceptionResolver and then handle the exception in the frontend.

```
fetch("http://httpstat.us/400")
  .then(...)
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.status === 400) {
      setCustomError(error.message)
    } else {
      console.error("Error:", e)
    }
  });
```